How much did Latin change from the 3rd to the 5th century AD?
I’m self-studying Latin with the goal
Of reading the Vulgate fluently (and because I love languages). I’ve read that the Vulgate was translated in the late 4th and early 5th centuries AD, but most of the Latin texts I’ve found from those periods are Church texts, and I’m trying to expand my vocabulary by reading more general Latin texts while sticking with Latin that’s close to that used in the Vulgate. I’m considering reading earlier texts and was wondering: how much did Latin change from the 3rd to the 5th century AD? For that matter, is Latin from the 5th century AD significantly different from that around the turn of time of Christ? Trying to figure out how far I can go back from the Vulgate without getting into a “different Latin”.

Note that the Vulgate has a very distinctive style—Jerome was extremely literal in translating Greek and Hebrew idioms into things that don't make a lot of sense in pure Latin.

@Draconis: I thought that the Vulgate, like Cicero, could be relied upon for high-quality Latin. Do you have an example of something that does not make sense in (Does "pure" mean "classical"?) Latin?

@tony Off the top of my head, the fact that "why hast thou forsaken me" is translated with ut quid when it comes from the New Testament Greek (an extremely literal translation of hina ti) but quare when it comes from the Old Testament Hebrew (since Hebrew uses a single word for "why"). I don't think I've ever seen ut quid for "why" in Latin except when trying to adapt Greek word for word.
